# Visual Studio Won't Mark Errors

Tags: visual-studio, settings

I just upgraded from VS C# Express and VS would mark my errors on the fly and now in full VS 2008 they aren't marked until compile time.  I have checked the settings and have I have the check boxes marked for showing errors.  I have even reset the VS settings and that didn't work either.  I have the free version of devExpress, does anyone know if that would screw stuff up?

Thanks.

Comment: Some times plugins do reset some of the settings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Underline errors in the editor?

Comment: OK- try tools -> import and export settings -> Reset all settings. I had a load of other settings break once and that fixed them...

Comment: Uninstall any plugins, and then reset all settings?

Comment: @Joel- that sounds like a sensible next step